# From binary to base 48 conversion

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, dictionary, radix

I created a function that takes in a binary as a string then converts it to base48, it works for most test cases but when I run "1010000001101101011000000100000001000101111010000101101010110000001100110" through it

```
import math
def Binary2Octoquadragesimal(n):

     octdict = {"0":"0","1":"1","2":"2","3":"3","4":"4","5":"5","6":"6","7":"7","8":"8","9":"9","10":"a","11":"b","12":"c","13":"d","14":"e","15":"f","16":"g","17":"h","18":"i","19":"j","20":"k","21":"l","22":"m","23":"n","24":"o","25":"p","26":"q","27":"r","28":"s","29":"t","30":"u","31":"v","32":"w","33":"x","34":"y","35":"z","36":"A","37":"B","38":"C","39":"D","40":"E","41":"F","42":"G","43":"H","44":"I","45":"J","46":"K","47":"L",}


     ans = []

     if n == "":
         return ""

     i = int(n,2)

     if i == 0:
         return "0"

     while i > 0:
         ans.append(octdict[str(i%48)])
         i = math.floor(i/48)
     ans.reverse()
     print (ans)
     return ("".join(ans))
```

it comes back with the wrong value, I looked around my code a bit and it seems in this particular test case my function return Dragonfly00w6 instead of Dragonfly2026 why is this only happening in this case and not the others? and how can I remedy it

Comment: Use a debugger to see just where/when the program behaves differently than you expected.

Comment: I did some debugging and found that it converts to decimal properly but after that it messes up. I think there might be an issue with how the parts are being appended because otherwise the rest of the word would be wrong as well presumably

Comment: Determining *how* it "messes up" is how one figures out how to fix it.

Comment: Just a guess: Replace `math.floor(i/48)` by `i//48` to avoid any possible float calculation errors.

Comment: Changing math.floor to // worked! I didn't realize math.floor had that problem

Comment: As an aside, suggest using `oct='0123456789abc...'` and `oct[i%48]` to index a character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is floating point inaccuracies. The number is way too big to be represented by a python float. Ints work because python ints are arbitrary precision.

After doing a couple of iterations the problem fixes itself, because the error only occurs in the rest, the division hides the problem.

If you do `print(f"{i/48}, {math.floor(i/48)}, {i//48}")` in every iteration, you will see the problem:

```
1.2330668424210091e+20, 123306684242100912128, 123306684242100908546
2.568889255043769e+18, 2568889255043768832, 2568889255043769002
5.351852614674518e+16, 53518526146745184, 53518526146745184
1114969294723858.0, 1114969294723858, 1114969294723858
23228526973413.707, 23228526973413, 23228526973413
483927645279.4375, 483927645279, 483927645279
10081825943.3125, 10081825943, 10081825943
210038040.47916666, 210038040, 210038040
4375792.5, 4375792, 4375792
91162.33333333333, 91162, 91162
1899.2083333333333, 1899, 1899
39.5625, 39, 39
0.8125, 0, 0
```

You can clearly see that in the first two lines, the values are much too big to fit into a float, causing rounding issues.

Therefore, replacing `math.floor(i/48)` with `i//48` fixes the problem, as you directly compute a division from arbitrary precision to arbitrary precision, without forcing a float in between.